# Fantasy novel with a giant living city made of purple crystals that the protagonist can communicate with

Tags: story-identification

Ok this one is hurting my mind now.

Most details I can remember are:

- Giant Living 'city' made from Purple material
- Main Character can speak to/control the 'city'
- Magic is 'Will'?
- Remember there being multiple books,but couldn't say how many

Sorry I can't be more detailed, but it's hiding in the corner of my mind, just out of sight, and I'm just getting flashes.

(City may be called 'Kethinica', but I guessed the spelling)

Comment: Take a look [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) and see if you can remember anything else, however tangential it may seem. Don't forget you can [edit] your question at any time.

Comment: Was it a novel?   Was it a comic or graphic novel?

Comment: Possibly a longshot but the Void trilogy by Peter F. Hamilton, sci-fi, had a plot in a fantasy-esque world similar to that, the hero came to a city called Makkathran, but the capital of Querencia, which is vaguely similar.  The city IS crystal and the main character does learn various tricks to control it, and most people have will-based psi-type abilities.

Comment: Just adding this in case your experiencing a "Gestalt" memory :) https://archive.org/stream/galaxymagazine-1959-04/Galaxy_1959_04#page/n5/mode/2up there are parts of your description that fit well with this and some that do not. The city is built as geometrical shapes of many colors, some colors are dangerous some are not. Humans can talk to the shapes or more accurately listen to them as they have "organic brains" constantly "thinking" the shape. The force material is manipulated by just thinking about it. The hero does talk to a "sphere".

Comment: I may be being stupid but i cant accept your answer @starpilotsix , however that is the exact book/trilogy i was after, thank you so much, now i can go on tsome other random thing i cant remember :)

Comment: Is the city possibly made of 'frozen energy' that can be extracted from rings?  If so, you might be looking for https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59012/what-book-has-tall-transparent-cylindrical-column-shaped-aliens-defending-massiv/117587#117587

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be one of the storylines in the [Void Trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_Trilogy) by Peter F. Hamilton.  The series as a whole is SF, but that particular storyline is set inside the Void, where the laws of physics are somewhat different and the story resembles a fantasy story.

The main city is named Makkathran, which isn't similar to your memory, but the city is the capital of Querencia, which is, and the city is indeed made of a living crystal.

From a fan-wiki's description of [the Void](http://peterfhamilton.wikia.com/wiki/Void), we see what you remember about a sort of willpower-based 'magic', which is really psychic ability:

> The primary feature of the Void is that it inhibits and eventually prohibits the use of advanced technology, particularly electronics (or even electricity), thus rendering the society on the planet to be similar to 18th century Europe, i.e. the most advanced technology are semi-automatic firearms.
>
> On the other hand, the Void responds to the thoughts of its inhabitants, giving them pyschic powers, including perception at a distance (farsight), communication at a distance (longtalk) and telekinesis (the third hand). Inhabitants have these abilities at varying strengths, i.e. some people are stronger than other with each ability.

An entry on [the city](http://peterfhamilton.wikia.com/wiki/Makkakthran) itself includes what you remember of the main character learning to 'talk' to the city:

> As Edeard's powers grow, and he becomes more familiar with the city, he discovers that the city appears to have some form of awareness of its inhabitants and can respond to Edeard's requests to reshape stairs, or even walk through walls or sink through floors.